# POST JSON to webservice

Tags: java, android, json, post

I'm trying to connect to a web service and post JSON using this code but i don't know what im doing wrong. [edit]I wrote the same class using HTTPClient and it worked but since httpURLConnect is what google focuses on, I changed it to work with that.

The question is, am I sending properly formatted json? and is the way im sending it to the server the right way? I've marked the problem area
This is the helper class I'm using to connect and post the json:

```
package com.example.connecttohtml;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class HtmlHelper {
    public static JSONArray getData(RequestPackage p){
        JSONArray jsonArray;
        BufferedReader readData = null;
        String uri = p.getUri();

        if(p.getMethod().equals("GET")){
            uri += "?" + p.getEncodedParams();
        }

        try{
            URL url = new URL(uri);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod(p.getMethod());
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

            Log.d("getParams", p.getEncodedParams().toString());
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(p.getParams());
            String params = json.toString();

    ////THIS IS THE PART IM NOT SURE OF///////////////////////      
            if (p.getMethod().equals("POST")){

                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
                Log.d("jsonPassed", params);
                writer.write(params);
                writer.flush();
            }
//////////////////////////////////////END///////

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            readData = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while((line = readData.readLine()) != null){
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            jsonArray = new JSONArray(sb.toString());
            return jsonArray;

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }finally{
            if(readData !=null){
                try {
                    readData.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the RequestPackage class implementation code:

```
package com.example.connecttohtml;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class RequestPackage {
    private String uri;
    private String method = "GET";
    private Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    public String getUri() {
        return uri;
    }
    public void setUri(String uri) {
        this.uri = uri;
    }
    public String getMethod() {
        return method;
    }
    public void setMethod(String method) {
        this.method = method;
    }
    public Map<String, String> getParams() {
        return params;
    }
    public void setParams(Map<String, String> params) {
        this.params = params;
    }

    public void setParam(String key, String value){
        params.put(key, value);
    }

    public String getEncodedParams(){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for(String key : params.keySet()){
            String value = null;
            try {
                value = URLEncoder.encode(params.get(key), "UTF-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(sb.length()> 0 ){
                sb.append("&");
            }       
            sb.append(key + "=" + value);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }//getEncodedParams
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, "Let me post a whole bunch of code and have someone else figure out the problem" is not really what stackoverflow is for. You need to describe the actual problem, tell us what you've tried and where it's going wrong and add some *simple, relevant code*. In addition, adding swearing/bad language in your code is unlikely to get people to help you...

Comment: I've made edits to the code. The swear word thing wasn't intentional. it was already part of my code and i forgot to change it before posing it sorry about that.

Comment: use poster or other post client and verify your API is working as expected or log the result of "jsonArray = new JSONArray(sb.toString());" please

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I don't know what was wrong but I re-run the code  this morning and it worked perfectly.